# how av_freep in ffmpeg works?

Tags: c, pointers, ffmpeg

I have some questions regarding void pointer in C. I found out the following code, part of ffmpeg that I couldn't understand... Could someone explain to me how it works?

```
void av_freep(void *arg)
{
        void *val;

        memcpy(&val, arg, sizeof(val));
        memcpy(arg, &(void *){ NULL }, sizeof(val));
        av_free(val);
}
```

and later it's called like this:

```
char *str;
av_freep(&str);
```

my questions:

1. how passing address of str (&str) doesn't trigger "incompatible type" warning when it's compiled? Shouldn't &str type is become char**?
2. what's the meaning of &(void *){ NULL } in one of memcpy parameter?
3. why it's trying to free "val" which is not allocated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how passing address of str (&str) doesn't trigger "incompatible type" warning when it's compiled? Shouldn't &str type is become char**?

It is, and `char**` is implicitly convertible to `void *` (because every pointer type is implicitly convertible to `void *`).

> what's the meaning of &(void *){ NULL } in one of memcpy parameter?

It's a *compound literal* (even though `void *` isn't a compound type). The compiler allocates a constant `void *` holding `NULL`, and then `(&(void *){ NULL })` is a pointer to that. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
static void* const temp = NULL;
memcpy(arg, &temp, sizeof(val));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, more question, but what does it do? why need to memory copy NULL into arg? why we don't do simpler thing like arg = NULL;I'm lost here... Thanks!

Comment: @BillyBob `av_freep()` doesn't deallocate memory that is pointed to by its parameter. Instead its parameter is a pointer to pointer to freed data. And because of this function reads real pointer to freed data with first `memcpy()`. Then this pointer is passed to `av_free()` that acts like standard `free()`. And second `memcpy()` is used to erase that pointer in outer scope. E.g. `char *str; av_freep(&str);` - here block with address `str` is freed and `str` becomes `NULL` after `av_freep()`.  The purpose of such function is to reduce number of dangling pointers in your program.

Answer (score 4):

> how passing address of str (&str) doesn't trigger "incompatible type"
>   warning when it's compiled? Shouldn't &str type is become char**?

This is because of fact that `av_freep()` parameter is `void *` i.e. it is compatible with any type of data pointers. Of course code would be clearer if it was e.g. `void **`. In that case we explicitly see that function erases our pointer to avoid accidental future dereferences. But then we should use ugly casts for almost all usages of function, because `void **` is not compatible with arbitrary data pointer types.

> what's the meaning of &(void *){ NULL } in one of memcpy parameter?

It is so called compound literal, you may think about it like an local object with type `void *` that is initialised with `NULL`.